# Resetting Execution Plans

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-execution-plan

I am optimizing a query and am worried that SQL Server is caching execution plans so want to wipe them.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do this: [DBCC FREEPROCCACHE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174283.aspx);

I also do this [DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187762.aspx);

> Use DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS to test queries with a cold buffer cache
>   without shutting down and restarting the server.
>
> To drop clean buffers from the buffer pool, first use CHECKPOINT to
>   produce a cold buffer cache. This forces all dirty pages for the
>   current database to be written to disk and cleans the buffers. After
>   you do this, you can issue DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS command to remove all
>   buffers from the buffer pool.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use [DBCC FREEPROCCACHE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174283.aspx)

> Removes all elements from the plan cache, removes a specific plan from
>   the plan cache by specifying a plan handle or SQL handle, or removes
>   all cache entries associated with a specified resource pool.